# How to detect if the focus is on extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write a vscode extension which requires to do some background task but I want the background task to stop if the user hasn't selected the extension.

How can I know if the user has selected my extension or has some other view open which could be anything like other extnsion/file explorer view.

I tried checking if there is some context key which would help me know if my extension is currently in focus but no luck. Perphans any vscode api?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean when the extension is selected in the Extensions list and thus opened as an editor?

Comment: I mean when the extension is selected in the activity bar and it opens the extension's panel which may or may not open any editor I believe